# how to play a video in bootstrap modal in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to auto  play a video when bootstrap modal get open.I tried different way But nothing is working. What I am trying is when we click on anchor tag and I am calling one function to open a modal manually and placing video src dynamic. please help me. without modal If I display the video is playing.

without modal this is working

```
<video id="{{result.profileId._id}}" width="100%" height="200" controls style="margin:10px 0">
              <source src="{{result.url}}" poster="assets/images/avatar.png" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
```

html file

```
<div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let result of trendvideos">
        <div class="aud1 tr-vid card card-shadow">
            <div class="aud-blk"> 

             <a   (click)="getVideo(result.secureUrl)"   *ngIf="result?.profileId?.image.secureUrl != null" class="user-img mt-3" >
              <img class="img-fluid" src="{{result.profileId.image.secureUrl}}">
            </a>

            <a  (click)="getVideo(result.secureUrl)"   *ngIf="result?.profileId?.image.secureUrl == null" class="user-img mt-3">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/images/avatar.png">
            </a>

            <p><b> {{ result.likes }} </b><span><i class="fas fa-heart" style="color: red;"></i></span></p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <video id="video1" width="100%" height="200" controls autoplay style="margin:10px 0">
                <source  src="{{videoUrl}}" poster="assets/images/avatar.png" type="video/mp4">
              </video> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

typescript file for opening modal

```
getVideo(vidUrl) {
    //let videoid = event.getAttribute('data-value');
    console.log(vidUrl);
    this.videoUrl = vidUrl;
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
  }
```

Comment: use ng-bootstrap for modals get started here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind below bootstrap modal events in the ngOnInit() method. On opening modal i.e **'shown.bs.modal'** play video using **'play'** jQuery function and on close modal stop playing video. Make sure you are using JQuery in your angular project.

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('#video1')[0].play();
   }, 1000);
  // or use below JS code if not using jQuery
 /* var vid = document.getElementById("video1"); 
  vid.play(); */

})
$('#exampleModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#video1')[0].pause();
})
```

Comment: thank for replying I need to add this code in ngOninit method?

Comment: Yes add this in  ngOnInit() method of your component. Make sure you have modal HTML in that component only.

Comment: I am trying now. I let you know in a second

Comment: I am getting this error in console.log Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Comment: ohh. Can you please share angular code in stackblitz if possible. I will try to debug it. I am sure it's a small change only.

Comment: I have wrapped play method inside setTimeout. Try this also. Please check edited answer.

Comment: ohh ok. Request you to please share your code in stackblitz.

Comment: I tried to add but it is giving me an error. I am totally new to angular I am not understanding how to add sorry for that.